# Notation of complement of set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Given, $U=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\},A=\{1,2,3\}$. We have to find the complement of the set A.

We start by,

Since set $A=\{1,2,3\}$, so $A'=\{1,2,3\}'=\{4,5,6\}$

Is the second part where I write $A'=\{1,2,3\}'$ a valid way to write 'complement of set A' ? I say that because I am not sure if we can write $\{1,2,3\}'$ as a substitute to $U-A$. Also note that I am aware of other ways to write it.So my question is mostly just a yes-no one,but any other information you provide will be very much appreciated.

Comment: It is valid. Not really advisable, the $'$ is visually obscured.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas,Hmm. . .I should have posted it before I got a 0 out of 6 only because of notation.

Comment: I haven't seen $\{1,2,3\}'$ myself but I don't see anything wrong with it since it is equal to A' by definition.  Perhaps you should use bar notation or $A^{C}$.

Comment: @Christopher,that's what I told the teacher,but he refused to discuss the matter any further.

Comment: There are different notations.  As long as you have defined what you are using...

Comment: What exactly did your professor say?

Comment: @Christopher,as all we have been taught in the introductory chapter are just basic notations ,I don't think there is any reason for the teacher to think otherwise.

Comment: There are many notations... So long as they are defined throughout the course.

Comment: @Christopher,he said that it is invalid,and I was just going to argue about it being the same as A' but the bell rang.Moreover,the said that he had been instructed by the head of maths department to do so.

Comment: I disagree with it's invalidity, but again it's really not used so don't argue with the professor.

Comment: If you left the answer as $\{1,2,3\}'$,  I would agree with the instructor that you have done nothing, and $0$ is fully reasonable. If you used the notation, but ended up with answer $\{4,5,6\}$, it seems to me you know what you are doing, maybe a mark off so that the instructor can express her/his displeasure with the notation. But arguing about grades is not necessarily good strategy.

Comment: @Andre,I did not argue ,really.I just tried to see why I was wrong.And no,I didn't leave the answer as {1,2,3}'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Christopher Erst, I haven't ever seen $\{1, 2, 3\}'$ used, but since $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$, it follows that $A' = \overline A = A^C = \{1, 2, 3\}'$ is *valid,* though I wouldn't recommend it.

What I'd suggest is a more direct approach: $A' = \{4, 5, 6\}$ (to show directly that you know what the complement $A' = U - A$ is: writing $A'$ as the set whose members/elements belong to $A'$)?

Comment: I agree with @amWhy here.  I'd stay away from it.

Comment: I don't think the teacher would be satisfied with me defining what the complement of a set is.,actually.That said,thanks for the answer.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is this: Given the question: If $U = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}, \; A = \{1, 2, 3\}$, what is the complement of $A$?: I would not recommend answering as follows: $A' = \{1, 2, 3\}'$. That's just "playing with notation", and avoids answering the question. I would write $U - A $ is the complement $(A')$ of set $A$, where $A' = \{4, 5, 6\}$.

Comment: @amwhy,thanks.the original question gave three sets and asked us to prove (A U B)'=A' intersection B' or something similar.So I was n't really careful about all my notation,but it's my fault anyway.

Comment: @amwhy,I did not the leave the answer as {1,2,3}',because as you said ,that's just playing with notation.